# Why does Intellij display weird parameter names?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently started using Java for software development. Maybe my Settings in IntelliJ are wrong, but most of the time the parameters have weird names like `i, i1, i2, i3, i4, ...`. Is this normal or am I missing something?

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJOKJ.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Now8g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When IntelliJ tries to figure out the parameter names, it looks into the following places:

- Source code

  If you added source code to a library file, it uses the names from the source code for the names in the documentation
- Build jar file

  In most cases, the build jar file contains debug information about the parameter names, this is not always the case
- Random generated names

  If the above fails, it will generate random meaningless names, like `i1` for the first number parameter.

Comment: I'd say that the generated names are _systematic_ rather than random.